# Android RC app that doesn't try to be a multimedia pilot

Tags: android, remote-access

I need an app that can be used for remote control of simple devices connected to the net, be it through some open (or at least non-secret) protocol, or customizable, say, sending given strings over TCP/IP or making SSH connections.
In particular, [SSHmote](http://slideme.org/application/sshmote) and [Raspberry Pi Remote](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.raspberry.remote) would fit the bill.

My requirement though is a customizable interface, or even generic interface that doesn't try to make this into a media player remote. For example, the Raspberry Pi remote first demands to pick some multimedia files before even allowing to enter the 'remote control' part, despite defined commands never touching any files, and of all predefined interfaces of SSHmote, every single contains "play", "pause", "previous", "next" buttons. I'm sorry, but I don't want to activate (for example) garden irrigation with "play" and garage gate with "stop".

So, summarizing:

- an Android app - can be paid but I must be able to try it before purchase
- Remote commands over TCP/IP, either open protocol or customizable (ssh and the likes are okay, if I need, I can write a listening daemon for the target device).
- Customizable or fixed controls that allow activation/deactivation of selected device/channel (sending command upon click of a button) that don't try to suggest the target device is a media player.
- No clutter, like obtrusive requesters, 'please rate', 'buy our other apps' etc. Target functionality must be at most 2 clicks away from launch of the application.

Suggestions of apps that currently ARE media player remotes, but are open-sourced, so that I could edit the UI and customize it to my needs are okay.

Can you help?